# Why do hindus believe in karma theory?

Tags: karma

Why do Hindus believe in Karma theory?

I heard the rich and poor example by birth.

It says if there is no past karma then how a person becomes rich or poor by birth only to rich or poor parents.

It also says about kids with disabilities at the time of birth only.

Why one should believe that it is because of their fate only instead of something happened random?

Comment: This world is chain of events. Karana kariya is basis in which this shrishti runs. A person with good deeds can be born to poor parents but would be adopted by rich family somehow. Etc. Are how one of examples karma works

Comment: then you can also let government punish you even if you didn't commit crime, cos it's "just random".

Comment: Asking 'why' is asking for opinions. Please see forum rules. Why? Because the vedas assert karma and, by definition, to be a Hindu is to assert the vedas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karma is neither a theory nor a belief. Karma means action or intentional inaction.  If there are any doubts about this, one can try throwing a stone straight up one's head and continue to stay without moving. The Karma (action) and the Kartha (doer) and its result (Karma Phala) will become very evident. The karth (doer) might forget in due time that he/she threw a stone a few seconds ago, but neither the stone nor Earth's Gravity takes our memory into their consideration. Scientists concluded primates to be our closest evolutionary relative because that information is memorized in our DNA. The percentage gap between Homo Sapiens and Hominids is close to 1%. But that memory is on the physical level (DNA), what about nonbiological? Quantum Memory is there in everything. There are banks of memory in everything. Water doesn't confuse itself and becomes Fire tomorrow. An apple tree doesn't give peaches tomorrow, Earth doesn't take a holiday from revolving around the Sun. The Forces that come into play from the highest of cosmic phenomena also have a memory that is beyond the normal context of physical. This physical body is nothing but a piece of this planet that carries a huge bank of memory and so does other forces that make us conscious with intelligence. So assuming that a section of that memory doesn't get carried over beyond the physical by forces beyond the physical is just being willfully mulish.

Now, Yogic sciences have given precise vocabulary associated with what we discussed. Like Saṃskāra, Vasana, Upadhi, Prana, Sharira, Kosha, Jiva and many more. The collective memory that is carried over the current Upandhi (physical form), is also discussed in various literature of the Sanatana Culture. To what extent one wishes to explore the Karmic memory transfer in the current instance or over years or lifetimes depends upon the willingness of the seeker. [Here is an article on Karma Concept that can provide a subjective descript with examples.](http://sanatanadhara.com/karma/)
Source for concepts like Upashi, Jiva, Kosha, Sharira, and rebirth can be found on this [link](http://sanatanadhara.com/rebirth/).

Comment: you need to give references directly in your answer, links are not an answer.